# How to display all metrics that don't have a specific label

Tags: prometheus

I want to select all metrics that don't have label "container". Is there any possibility to do that with prometheus query?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
{__name__=~".+",container=""}
```

There needs to be at least one non-empty matcher (hence the `+` in the `__name__` regular expression, `*` wouldn't cut it). And the way you query for a missing label is by checking for equality with the empty string.

Answer (score 13):

In recent versions of Prometheus it's enought to query for something like this:

```
node_load1{not_existent_label=""}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try checking if the label is or isn’t equal to the empty string.

```
metric_name{label_name=""}
```

Or, try label data integrity [checks](https://docs.deepchecks.com/en/stable/examples/checks/integrity/index.html) form [deepchecks](https://docs.deepchecks.com/en/stable/index.html)

All the best!